# Import com.google.api cannot be resolved

Tags: java, api, gradle

I'm working with Google sheet API on eclipse.

When I am trying to import different libraries from com.google.api,

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
```

I'm facing with problem `The import com.google.api cannot be resolved`
[image: import com.google.api error]

despite I've added the following dependencies to to build.gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev516-1.23.0'
```

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be performing gradle build task may help.

Also right btn click on project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project may be required.

Comment: You use "may" three times. Please phrase a more assertively helpful answer.